# upload file and other attributes with AJAX django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I want to upload my file with some other attributes using AJAX

My AJAX code:

```
        var file = $('#uploaded-file').get(0).files[0]
        if (file != null) {
            var reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = function () {
                var filedata = reader.result;
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/upload_file',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                    data:JSON.stringify({'data':filedata, 'name':file.name}),
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log(response)
                    }
                })

            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
        }
```

My Djnago view.py:

```
def upload_file(request):
    print(json.loads(request.body))
    return JsonResponse({'response':'request done'})
```

however i am not getting file data in my request body

```
{'data': {}, 'name': 'abc.csv'}
```

what i am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use `FormData`

```
var file = $('#uploaded-file').get(0).files[0]

var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("file", file, file.name);
formData.append("some_other_field", 'value');


    $.ajax({
                url: '/upload_file',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
                },
                data: formData
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response)
                },
                contentType: false,
                processData: false, // important
            })
```

to get the file in Django:

```
request.FILES.getlist('file')
```

Comment: request.POST.get('file') just return '[object ArrayBuffer]' and it is string only

Comment: @Hassam check the updated answer. you have to use `request.FILES` to get file